# Discord.py | How do I get a User Tag from an ID?

Tags: discord.py

I am programming an entertainment bot with discord.py, and I want to code a function that allows you to look at other users' in game money and stuff with replit databases. Since making data with a user tag is inefficient since people change their usernames and tags all the time, I am using IDs. I am trying to find a way to get a user tag (eg. Dude#1234) from a user number id (eg. 871954599731396648). I couldn't find a solution. I already know how to use ctx.message.author.id but I can't find a way to make that work with every discord user.

Answer (score 1):

To get the tag you can use the following method

```py
user = await bot.fetch_user(ID) # ID must be an int and this could be could be client for you, be careful as this pings the API and can be abused if not correctly limited.

# user.discriminator will return their tag.
```

You can check all attributes that `user` can have [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User)

Answer (score 0):

To get the tag, you first have to get the user object from the id using `discord.utils.get`:

```py
user_id = #insert the id of the user which you want the tag of
user = await discord.utils.get(client.get_all_members(), id =user_id)#might by something like bot.get_all_members for you
tag = user.name
```